# How to assign angularjs variable value to html element attribute, such as input elememnt's name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am totally new to angular, I have an angularjs $scope variable:

```
$scope.testme = "inputname",
```

and I want to assign this variable value to a name attribute of html  element. I want

the below result:

`<input name="inputname" ...>`. But how to get it from angularjs scope variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see more https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

[image]

```js
var app= angular.module("app",[]).controller('fCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.elementName = "testName";
$scope.myElement = {
  value:"some value",
  name:"myInput"
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="fCtrl">
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="myElement.value" name="{{myElement.name}}">
  <hr/>
  name only
  <br/>
  
  <input type="text" name="{{elementName}}">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need a name attribute in input element, this is the question I asked.

Comment: @user1342336 do you want set name attribute ?

Comment: I tested it, the {{myElement.name}} seemed not equal to "myInput". Can I remove ng-model? I have an old html code, when name="something", a value would be assigned to 'true' or 'false' for a checkbox. So I don't need put ng-model there. If I put ng-model="true" or "false", the checkbox will take it's value, so name attribute is useless here, now I still want to use the old value assigned to name attribute. Sorry, it is a little bit messy. Thank you for your wonderful answer.