# Why can't I use interpolation with a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, interpolation

I have searched and found a few articles that address "How does one assign a scoped variable to the value of an html attribute tag". See:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

[How to assign angularjs variable value to html element attribute, such as input elememnt's name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963591/how-to-assign-angularjs-variable-value-to-html-element-attribute-such-as-input)

In my controller I have defined the following:

```
    $scope.reportFields = "{'summary.imageID':'Image ID' }";
```

in my html document I have defined the following:

```
    <a href="{{reportFields}}">A TEST EXAMPLE</a>
    <button ng-json-eport-excel title="CSV" class="bt btn-md btn-success" separator="," data="mdcData" report-fields="{{reportFields}}" filename="'mySearch'">
```

when I bring the page into the browser I find that the page reports a parse syntax error on defining {{reportFields}} for my button element.

```
     Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax error: Token '{' invlaid key at column 2 of the expression [{{reportFields}}] starting at [reportFields}}].
```

if I forgo using a variable and hardcode the value as in:

```
    <button ng-json-eport-excel title="CSV" class="bt btn-md btn-success" separator="," data="mdcData" report-fields="{'summary.imageID':'Image ID' }" filename="'mySearch'">
```

it compiles and works correctly. If I add the 'ng-if' it compiles correctly as seen below:

```
    <button ng-json-eport-excel title="CSV" class="bt btn-md btn-success" separator="," data="mdcData" report-fields="{{reportFields}}" ng-if="reportFields.length > 0" filename="'mySearch'">
```

Furthermore when I examine the generated HTML via the inspector I can see that for the 'ahref' tag that angularjs's interpolation has translated 'reportFields' to '"{'summary.imageID':'Image ID' }"' for the ahref tag but it hasn't translate the value for the report-fields tag specified on the button.  I have also tried:

```
    ng-if="1==1" filename="'mySearch'">
```

for my expression which should always evaluate to true. My questions (and I am new to angularjs and I need help understanding) are:

1. Why do I get a syntax parse error for using the double curly angles with the second HTML element (button) but not the first (href)??
2. Why does the parse error go away with the 'ng-if' statement
3. Why doesn't the interpolation happen in the case for

   ```
    report-fields="{{reportFields}}"
   ```

   but occurs just fine for:

   ```
    <a href="{{reportFields}}">A TEST EXAMPLE</a>
   ```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Pete

Comment: Is that some type of angular directive you're using on the `<button>`? If so, you don't need the interpolation characters when assigning a scope value to a directive attribute.

Comment: Hey, I answered your question. Care to upvote, clarify, accept?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

```
<a ng-href="reportFields">A TEST EXAMPLE</a>
```

Although this doesn't make any sense either given the way you've defined `reportFields`.  Notice the `ng-href` and lack of interpolation.  As it is, you are assigning the `reportFields` expression to the regular HTML attribute `href` which is not interpreted by Angular.

Angular treats your HTML like a template rather than trying to render it like a browser would.  It takes that template and turns it into browser-readable DOM HTML.  This helps explain the behavior you're asking about.

**Answers to your questions:**

1. Interpolation (curly braces) is actually a directive with special syntax which the parser has to evaluate along with any other directives such as `ng-show`, `ng-repeat`, custom directives, etc.  There is no guarantee that an interpolation directive will be processed before another directive that tries to bind to it.  And in fact, those other directives such as `report-fields` will get the raw interpolation markup and not the intended data.  This is what throws the error.  See the last paragraph in the interpolation documentation

   > [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)

   Since `href` is not actually a directive-- it's an attribute-- Angular doesn't attempt to treat it as a directive or bind it to the interpolation, so no error is thrown.  It just outputs the expected result to the DOM: `href="parsed value"`.
2. `ng-if` has no special assistance for this issue except it does get parsed before your `report-fields` directive and then cancels further parsing on the element if `false`.  If you don't get an error in that situation, it's likely only because the `if` condition evaluated to false and the `report-fields` directive was never parsed.  (Can't see all your code to confirm.)
3. The interpolation doesn't happen in the error case because the error is thrown before it has a chance to.  Again, this is because it gets processed after other directive linking.  (I'm not sure why they made that design choice though I imagine there is a good reason.)

Comment: The use of:    _ **`<a href="{{reportFields}}">A TEST EXAMPLE</a>`**_
was just a test to see if the extrapolation occurred. It did and oddly enough it compiled as well. If I set the attribute _i **`report-fields = {{ reportFields}}`**_ it didn't compile. I also tried setting _ **`report-fields=reportFields`**_ to no avail.

Comment: As a general rule, there's almost never a reason to use the interpolation braces inside of tags/attributes. You use it BETWEEN tags. `<a href="">{{HERE}}</a>` but `<a href="{{NOT HERE}}">asdf</a>`. Use expressions everywhere else (just quotes, no braces).